# Как вытаскивать данные с REST API при помощи Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Есть сайт,  реализованный на Meteor + Reactjs. Нужно вытягивать данные с REST API. Хочу сделать при помощи Apollo, на их сайте в документации про это есть один параграф,  но не понятно. Кто знает подскажите как это реализовать,  или статьи про реализацию.

Comment: аполло клиент и сервер работают с graphql конечными точками

Answer (score 0):

Apollo использует язык GraphQL для запросов и он не совместим с REST API. Поэтому никак, используйте для запросов встроенную в метеор библиотеку для запросов или либу `request`.